# I can't automatically configure the Google Tag Manager server with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCCrO.png)I'm having trouble configuring the conversions API, I can't do it automatically and I can't do it manually either
Follow print below

Answer (score 0):

This Google bug. Google already knows about it.

You can try [sGTM hosting from Stape.io](https://stape.io/gtm-server-hosting)